# how to make activity layout to specific size

Tags: android

I want to show my app to run onto another application.
If i set the width *200dp* and height *50dp* then it shows okay.
But if I want to interact with another app, I can't.
For example, I start Google Chrome browser, then I open my app. As my app's width is *200dp* and height is *50dp*, I should copy any text from the Chrome browser.
What should i do?

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

go through the following links

[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

[Supporting tablets](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html)